# In Unity 5, My GUI textures don't show up in the APK build but they DO show in the editor

Tags: android, apk, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity that has GUI textures that I added as shown in the picture:

[image: As you can see in the game mirror, I have my music and reset buttons added as GUI textures]

[image]

As you can see in the game mirror, I have my music and reset buttons added as GUI textures
However, they don't show up in my APK build, how can I fix this?
I've even tried using Unity Remote in which the GUI textures worked. However, in the apk doesn't work.

Comment: The text of the question seems to be trunced

Comment: I am sorry, but what does that exactly mean?

Comment: The question ends with _"I've even tried using"_ which looks like a start of a sentence without its end.

Comment: oh :/ Let me fix that in a second